# ClobberWarning with a simple conda build

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda, conda-build

I am trying to build a simple package (only python code) and I get this warning:

```
ClobberWarning: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: conda-forge/noarch::tomli-2.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0, conda-forge/osx-arm64::mypy-1.2.0-py311he2be06e_0
  path: 'lib/python3.11/site-packages/tomli/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc'
```

I followed the suggested practice of installing packages from the same channel, but yet I got this issue.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This has now [been patched](https://github.com/conda-forge/mypy-feedstock/pull/110). Would need to update to latest build of v1.7.1 (or higher) to get the fix.

---

### Original answer

Looks like a bug in the Conda Forge `mypy` feedstock, i.e., `mypy` shouldn't be capturing files from the `site-packages/tomli` directory. There is [an Issue filed for this](https://github.com/conda-forge/mypy-feedstock/issues/97) on the feedstock.

Since the version of `tomli` is very likely the same as what `mypy=1.2.0` was built with, it is likely safe to ignore. Maybe consider running [some of the tests](https://github.com/hukkin/tomli/tree/2.0.1/tests) just to get peace of mind. Otherwise, would need to wait for feedstock to be updated.